# Can an UITableViewCell be overlapped by other cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to implement a view which contains a google map and an UITableView, and the first section should overlap the map, the map should be scrolled with the table view.

I want to add the map in an UITableViewCell, but can the UITableViewCell with map be overlapped under the second section ?

You can see the attachement:

[image]

Comment: To create your desired effect you either need to add a tableView to a Viewcontroller. Because as far I know cells will not overlap, however if you need more flexibility I would recommend using a collection view controller and creating you own flow layout

Comment: @OverD 's suggestion is quite advance, which can handle any aspect for your application's future requirement. But it can be done easily just tweaking the `clipToBounds` property of cell, but in that case you will not be able to handle any touch/tap event in the overlapping area.

Comment: @RatulSharker which means I can use `clipToBounds` to add the map as a subview larger than the cell? Sounds I can get a try with that. But of course @OverD 's suggestion is good, just it would be a bit complicated to redo all by collection view...

Comment: Yes exactly it is. Let us know the result.

Comment: @RatulSharker It worked with `clipsToBounds`, but if I scroll back from the top to the first section (technically it's the second section), the map will be above it. Do you have any idea to solve it ?

Comment: you can try tweaking the table style from `Grouped` to `Plain` in the interface builder.

Comment: Why not just combine the first two cells into one cell styled the way you want?

Comment: @slickdaddy Because the first section is expandable...